# Geolocation is not working in safari 5.1.7

Tags: safari, geolocation

I am using safari  5.1.7 browser. I am using wired cable internet connection. I am making an application in which i need to use geolocation  Service in home page. when application starts it ask to allow share location and if we allow to share location , it gives error like, It give result like "Unable to retrieve your location". While it is working fine in WiFi internet connection.

Please review following link
1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation
2. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Please provide me solution why geolocation is not working in wired cabled internet connection? Why it is working for Wifi internet connection?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geolocation service is more accurate when there is a wifi connection. The Safari browser will passed the router MAC addresses to the geolocation server to pinpoint the location.

If there is no WIFI routers, it is hardly to pinpoint the location by high accuracy. Therefore, the browser does not provide any geolocation information.